# Cannot find python executable being used by QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin for QGIS but I am having trouble setting up my IDE with the required python executable so I can get a console working for logging output while developing it.  When I deliberately enter some messed up text in the script, and then try to run the plugin in QGIS, I can see an error in the stacktrace that I would assume indicates where the executable is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/isaac/.qgis2/python/plugins/MakeOSMRoutableNetwork/__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .make_osm_routable_network import MakeOSMRoutableNetwork
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/isaac/.qgis2/python/plugins/MakeOSMRoutableNetwork/make_osm_routable_network.py", line 214
    self.dlg.postgis_connection_listView.addItem(k)weqweqfasfsdf
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So it seems like my python exectuable is in `/usr/lib/python2.7`.  Alright, fair enough.  But when I navigate to this directory and list the contents, I don't see any python executable.  Shouldn't there be one in here? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You can open a python window in QGIS (plugins::Python Console) and get the path from there, print '\n'.join(sys.path)... other suggestions don't seem to work for me, sys.executable returns QGIS, which/where python returns a syntax error. Another interesting method is to import in the python window (from qgis import core) and then type *core* and hit enter, it will bring up a module description which includes path. These both work on Windows and may or may not work for Linux; of course which/where python may actually do *something* on Linux.

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7 is not your executable nor where it should be. It's where the various modules get installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python2.7` is your python.

Actually, you can use any of `/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2` or `/usr/bin/python2.7`

i.e. (On 17.04):

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ file `which python`
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to python2.7
$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
$ file `which python2`
/usr/bin/python2: symbolic link to python2.7
$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
$ file `which python2.7`
/usr/bin/python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b0407272b6bf54e757c18df5a69a7b6468c08b64, stripped
```

Why isn't your python in `/usr/lib`?  According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which defines the layout of Linux filesystems, `/usr/bin` is the primary directory for executable commands for all users and`/usr/lib` includes object files and libraries for the commands in `/usr/bin`.